# group by clause creating wrong result

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

When using aggregate functions you must include all of the other columns selected inside of a group by clause, but doing so the result becomes incorrect. Take this as an example:

```
SELECT Squadre.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Codice, Ruoli.Descrizione, MAX(Giocatori.Valore) AS 
       ValGiocatore
FROM (SELECT Squadre.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Codice, Ruoli.Descrizione, Giocatori.Valore
             FROM (((Squadre
             INNER JOIN Campionato ON Squadre.Codice = Campionato.CodSquadra)
             INNER JOIN Giocatori ON Campionato.CodGiocatore = Giocatori.Codice)
             INNER JOIN Ruoli ON Giocatori.CodRuolo = Ruoli.Codice))
GROUP BY Squadre.Codice, Ruoli.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Descrizione;
```

This code select all the teams from a league and returns the highest cost of a player for each role, and it works.
But if I wanted to also include the player's name and code in the result i would have to add them into the group by clause like this:

```
SELECT Squadre.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Codice, Ruoli.Descrizione, Giocatori.Codice, Giocatori.Nominativo, 
       MAX(Giocatori.Valore) AS ValGiocatore
FROM (SELECT Squadre.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Codice, Ruoli.Descrizione, Giocatori.Codice, 
             Giocatori.Nominativo, Giocatori.Valore
      FROM (((Squadre
      INNER JOIN Campionato ON Squadre.Codice = Campionato.CodSquadra)
      INNER JOIN Giocatori ON Campionato.CodGiocatore = Giocatori.Codice)
      INNER JOIN Ruoli ON Giocatori.CodRuolo = Ruoli.Codice))
GROUP BY Squadre.Codice, Ruoli.Codice, Squadre.Nome, Ruoli.Descrizione, Giocatori.Codice, Giocatori.Nominativo;
```

The result of this is wrong because it won't group it by roles anymore, but by players' codes.
**You can try yourself to run the code here**
http://www.itcgfermi.org/query/kxyz.aspx

Comment: @KenWhite yeah, the previous question was a dumb one I realised, since I didn't even need to use a group by clause in that case, this one is the one I should've asked from the start

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: The query does what it is designed to do, just not what you want. Retrieving name that goes with the Max(Valore) will likely involve a nested TOP N sql. Research "query TOP N per group"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using layered queries where you save different components for different uses. In MS Access, layer queries tend to be more efficient than subqueries. Below uses table aliases to shorten SQL and avoid same named columns.

**Join Query** *(save as named Query object)*

```sql
SELECT s.Codice AS Squadre_Codice, s.Nome AS Squadre_Nome, 
     r.Codice AS Ruoli_Codice, r.Descrizione AS Ruoli_Descrizione,
     g.Valore
FROM (((Squadre s
INNER JOIN Campionato c ON s.Codice = c.CodSquadra)
INNER JOIN Giocatori g ON c.CodGiocatore = g.Codice)
INNER JOIN Ruoli r ON g.CodRuolo = r.Codice)
```

**Aggregate Query** *(save as named Query object)*

```sql
SELECT sub.Squadre_Codice, sub.Squadre_Nome, 
       sub.Ruoli_Codice, sub.Ruoli_Descrizione,
       MAX(sub.Valore) AS ValGiocatore
FROM join_query AS sub
GROUP BY sub.Squadre_Codice, sub.Squadre_Nome, 
         sub.Ruoli_Codice, sub.Ruoli_Descrizione;
```

**Aggregate Query with Details**

```sql
SELECT agg.Squadre_Codice, agg.Squadre_Nome, 
       agg.Ruoli_Codice, agg.Ruoli_Descrizione,
       jn.Giocatori_Codice, jn.Giocatori_Nominativo
       MAX(agg.Valore) AS ValGiocatore
FROM  my_aggregate_query agg
INNER JOIN my_join_query jn
  ON  agg.Squadre_Codice = jn.Squadre_Codice
  AND agg.Squadre_Nome = jn.Squadre_Nome
  AND agg.Ruoli_Codice = jn.Ruoli_Codice
  AND agg.Ruoli_Descrizione = jn.Ruoli_Descrizione
```

---

Hopefully soon, in the not too distant future, MS Access will join its other DBMS counterparts to support common table expressions for single statement with layered derived sources:

```
WITH jn AS (
    -- SAME AS ABOVE
), agg AS (
    -- SIMILAR TO ABOVE WITH NEW
    -- FROM CLAUSE: jn AS sub
)

SELECT agg.Squadre_Codice, agg.Squadre_Nome, 
       agg.Ruoli_Codice, agg.Ruoli_Descrizione,
       jn.Giocatori_Codice, jn.Giocatori_Nominativo
       MAX(agg.Valore) AS ValGiocatore
FROM agg
INNER JOIN jn
  ON  agg.Squadre_Codice = jn.Squadre_Codice
  AND agg.Squadre_Nome = jn.Squadre_Nome
  AND agg.Ruoli_Codice = jn.Ruoli_Codice
  AND agg.Ruoli_Descrizione = jn.Ruoli_Descrizione
```